# Show value of variable from a different entry in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, variables

I have a nested form. The form is a model called list, which has a :name and a :month attribute. This list model has another model nested inside called item, which has a :name and :amount attributes. A list has many items, and an item belongs to a list. I created a variable in my controller (not sure if that's the best way) that totals all of the item amounts like this:

```
@amount_total = Item.where(:list_id => @list).sum("amount")
```

I call this variable in my list show page and it shows the total of all item amounts for the current list id. What I want to do is be able to compare the current list total to the previously entered list. Is it possible to do using a variable like this? If so, how? If not, what should I do?

**EDIT**

In my show action in the controller I have the following(based on the answer below):

```
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
```

But I need to create the variable @previous_list, something like this:

```
@previous_list = List.order("id").where("id<? AND user_id=?", self.id, self.user_id).last
```

I need to find the previously entered list but for the same user. However, when I put it the variable this way, it says there is an undefined method "user_id". Thoughts?

Comment: Does your User model have a belongs_to relationship with List?  Does List have a has_many relationship with User? Also, you probably want to use created_at to order your query, not id.  Id is not necessarily chronological, whereas created_at always will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from ipd got me closest to the solution, and here is how I completed it for my particular situation:

To show the previous list total - List Helper:

```
def prev_total(list)
list and list.items.sum("amount")
end
```

In the list.rb model:

```
def previouslist 
    self.class.order("id").where("id<? AND user_id=?", self.id, self.user_id).last
end
```

Then in my list show.html.erb file:

```
<%= prev_total(@list.previouslist) %>
```

It works just great!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably move this logic into your List model, and create a total_amount accessor in there, like:

```
def total_amount
  Item.where(:list_id => self.id).sum("amount")
end
```

Then in your controller you just need to load up the previous list into a @previous_list variable.

In your views you will then be able to do:

```
<%= @list.total_amount %>
<%= @previous_list.total_amount %>
```

ian.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. Sorry for maybe a dumb question, but where and how do I define the @list and @previous_list variables?

Comment: Good question!  This you will do in your controller 'show' action, most likely.  How exactly you implement it will depend on your intent, what previous list do you want to load?  What do you mean by previous?

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost there, but still just missing something. I put it in the edits above.